# $y''''+\frac{1}{t}y''+y=e^t, \ \ \ y(1)=0,\ y'(1)=2,\ y''(1)=1,\ y'''(1)=\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''''+\frac{1}{t}y''+y=e^t, \ \ \ y(1)=0,\ y'(1)=2,\ y''(1)=1,\  y'''(1)=\pi$$

How can I determine an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$, as large as possible, such that the solution $y(t)$ of the above intitial value problem exists on $I$?

How can I solve the differential equation? The $\frac{1}{t}$ is irritating. I tried setting $y=e^{\lambda t}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$y''''+\dfrac{1}{t}y''+y=e^t$

$ty''''+y''+ty=te^t$

Let $y_p=\int_a^be^{ts}K(s)~ds$ ,

Then $t\int_a^bs^4e^{ts}K(s)~ds+\int_a^bs^2e^{ts}K(s)~ds+t\int_a^be^{ts}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_a^b(s^4+1)e^{ts}K(s)~d(ts)+\int_a^bs^2e^{ts}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_a^b(s^4+1)K(s)~d(e^{ts})+\int_a^bs^2e^{ts}K(s)~ds=0$

$[(s^4+1)e^{ts}K(s)]_a^b-\int_a^be^{ts}~d((s^4+1)K(s))+\int_a^bs^2e^{ts}K(s)~ds=0$

$[(s^4+1)e^{ts}K(s)]_a^b-\int_a^b((s^4+1)K'(s)+4s^3K(s))e^{ts}~ds+\int_a^bs^2e^{ts}K(s)~ds=0$

$[(s^4+1)e^{ts}K(s)]_a^b-\int_a^b((s^4+1)K'(s)+(4s^3-s^2)K(s))e^{ts}~ds=0$

$\therefore(s^4+1)K'(s)+(4s^3-s^2)K(s)=0$

$(s^4+1)K'(s)=(s^2-4s^3)K(s)$

$\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}=\dfrac{s^2}{s^4+1}-\dfrac{4s^3}{s^4+1}$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}~ds=\int\dfrac{s^2}{s^4+1}~ds-\int\dfrac{4s^3}{s^4+1}~ds$

$\ln K(s)=\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2s+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2s-1)}{2\sqrt2}+\dfrac{\ln(s^2-\sqrt2s+1)}{4\sqrt2}-\dfrac{\ln(s^2+\sqrt2s+1)}{4\sqrt2}-\ln(s^4+1)+c_1$

(according to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+s%5E2%2F%28s%5E4%2B1%29)

$K(s)=\dfrac{c(s^2-\sqrt2s+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}-1}e^{\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2s+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2s-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{(s^2+\sqrt2s+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}+1}}$

$\therefore y_c=\int_a^b\dfrac{c(s^2-\sqrt2s+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}-1}e^{ts+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2s+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2s-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{(s^2+\sqrt2s+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}+1}}~ds$

But since the above procedure in fact suitable for any complex number $s$ ,

$\therefore y_{c,n}=\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dfrac{c_n((k_nr)^2-\sqrt2k_nr+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}-1}e^{tk_nr+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{((k_nr)^2+\sqrt2k_nr+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}+1}}~d(k_nr)=k_nc_n\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dfrac{(k_n^2r^2-\sqrt2k_nr+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}-1}e^{k_ntr+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{(k_n^2r^2+\sqrt2k_nr+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}+1}}~dr$

For some $t$-independent real number choices of $a_n$ and $b_n$ and $t$-independent complex number choices of $k_n$ such that:

$\lim\limits_{r\to a_n}\dfrac{(k_n^2r^2-\sqrt2k_nr+1)^\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}e^{k_ntr+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{(k_n^2r^2+\sqrt2k_nr+1)^\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}}=\lim\limits_{r\to b_n}\dfrac{(k_n^2r^2-\sqrt2k_nr+1)^\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}e^{k_ntr+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{(k_n^2r^2+\sqrt2k_nr+1)^\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}}$

$\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dfrac{(k_n^2r^2-\sqrt2k_nr+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}-1}e^{k_ntr+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr+1)}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2k_nr-1)}{2\sqrt2}}}{(k_n^2r^2+\sqrt2k_nr+1)^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}+1}}~dr$ converges